# setAttribute('src','page.html') is not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript to rotate pages in a `iframe` tag every 5 seconds.

```
function setPage() {
    if (i == pages.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    alert(pages[i]); //verify the right url is there
    var elmnt = document.getElementById('dashboard');
    elmnt.setAttribute('src', pages[i]);

    i++;
}
setInterval("setPage()", 5000);
```

The loop, interval, etc., is working. However, nothing changes for the `src` attribute of my `iframe` tag.

I tested with both IE8 and Chrome.

What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish that (no jQuery...)

Comment: Have you tried `elmnt.src = pages[i]`?

Comment: Rather verify that `elmnt` is there. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @VisioN - yes, I did: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @Amarundo It means that `elmnt` is not the element you require.

Comment: @Bergi - no errors - I even `alert(elmnt.id)` and I get "dashboard"

Comment: @VisioN - that is my question: why not? It means `src` is not a property.

Comment: @VisioN - you're right. sorry, silly mistake of mine - I was looking at the `id` of the `<div>`, and not of the `<iframe>` Please add an answer here. THanks.

Comment: @Amarundo Yes, I was assuming that. Added the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use `elmnt.src = pages[i]` instead.

If it still gives you error, then most probably you are trying to target element, that doesn't have `src` property. Check that `elemt.tagName` gives you `IFRAME`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just manually setting the src property of the iframe?

```
document.getElementById('dashboard').src = pages[i];
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Be careful with that.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it now, each time `setPage` gets called, the value `i` is `undefined`; if you want the value of `i` to be held from call to call, you need to set it in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work):

```
var setPage = (function () {
    var i = 0;
    return function () {
        if (i == pages.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        var elmnt = document.getElementById('dashboard');
        elmnt.setAttribute('src', pages[i]);
        i++;
    }
}());
```

Also when setting the interval, the first argument should just be the name of the function, no quotes or parens:

```
setInterval(setPage, 5000);
```

There's a couple other tweaks you could make to it, but that should get it running.

Comment: The counting logic is correct. I `alert` the value of `pages[i]` and it's giving me the right value. `i` is  set to `0` only when `i` reaches the length of the array.

Comment: You sure? Just using what you have above, `i` is going to be `undefined` each time `setPage` is called.

Comment: Yes. I works. Not all the code is here, though. `i=0` is before the function, after the `<script>` tag.