# YouTube-like /watch page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm trying to make a watch page like the YouTube watch page.

> Example of YouTube watch page URL: [/watch?v=J3atcU_7yxA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3atcU_7yxA) 
>  Example of my watch page URL: [/watch/?s=mindfield&e=isolation](https://youtubered.neocities.org/watch/?s=mindfield&e=isolation)

I'm trying to achieve that with this JavaScript code:

```
var url = new URL(document.URL);
var s = url.searchParams.get("s");
var e = url.searchParams.get("e");

if (s == "mindfield" && e == "isolation") {
  player('https://youtube.com/embed/iqKdEhx-dD4');
};

function player(source) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("src", source);
}
```

But it's just not working and I don't know why!

If you would like [here is the website](https://youtubered.neocities.org/watch/?s=mindfield&e=isolation) of where I'm trying to achieve that.

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably remove that link and then not link that page to any else. The content you are showing _(as I'm sure you are aware)_ are property of youtube _(youtube-red)_ and sharing it would probably be considered an illegal action.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working". The player loads with the link provided in the `if`.

Comment: @yuriy636 I changed the embed video to [this](https://youtu.be/J3atcU_7yxA) so if you access the website with these parameters (?s=mindfield&e=isolation) you should get [this](https://youtu.be/iqKdEhx-dD4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setAttribute('src','page.html') is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574305/setattributesrc-page-html-is-not-working)